# CAKeyframeAnimation for backgroundColor...causes crash

Tags: core-animation, background-color, cakeyframeanimation

I enumerate an array with this code and it crashes. I think it is because I am wrapping the colors incorrectly, but how should I pass them?

```
    CAKeyframeAnimation *iAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"backgroundColor"];
    NSArray *iTimes;
    NSArray *iValues;
    NSInteger iTag = iButton.tag;

    iTimes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
              [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(iTimeBlock * iTag)],
              [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(iTimeBlock * iTag + 1)],
              [NSNumber numberWithFloat:iTimeBlock * (iTag + 2)], nil];

    iValues = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
               iButton.backgroundColor,
               iButton.color, // my subclass has this property
                       iButton.backgroundColor, nil];

    [iAnimation setKeyTimes:iTimes];
    [iAnimation setValues:iValues];
    [iAnimation setDuration:21.0];
    [iButton.layer addAnimation:iAnimation
                         forKey:@"FlashColor"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    iValues = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
               (id)iButton.backgroundColor.CGColor,
               (id)iButton.color.CGColor,
               (id)iButton.backgroundColor.CGColor,
               nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the color of a UIButton you can do like this :

[iButton backgroundColor];

you probably don't need this stuff :

> [NSValue
>   valueWithBytes:iButton.backgroundColor
>                                 objCType:@encode(UIColor)],

Comment: getting the uicolor object isn't the issue, I stated out by passing the object in the way you describe. (edited to show first method)

Comment: Have you got some red errors ? 
Maybe, try this : [NSValue valueWithBytes:[iButton backgroundColor] objCType:@encode(UIColor)]